# bq_auth() error "could not find function" despite bigrquery package being installed and added to library

Tags: r

I have an R markdown file with the following lines of code

```
#install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("bigrquery")
library(bigrquery)
#install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
#install.packages("assertr")
library(assertr)

### google drive and sheets authentication

### If this is your first time using the report remove
# run drive_auth() without any email input
# This function will open an oauth permissions dealy through
# a browser and then cache the results of that.

#install.packages("googledrive")
library(googledrive)
#install.packages("googlesheets4")
library(googlesheets4)

drive_auth('mackenzie.egbert@newswhip.com')

gs4_auth(email = 'mackenzie.egbert@newswhip.com')
bq_auth(email = 'mackenzie.egbert@newswhip.com')
```

The issue is on the last line where I get an error message back reading *"Error in drive_auth("mackenzie.egbert@newswhip.com") :
could not find function "drive_auth"".*

Any ideas why this is happening? When I download and add the bigrquery package this is what I see in the console...

```
 install.packages("bigrquery")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kenzi/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/bigrquery_1.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 834126 bytes (814 KB)
downloaded 814 KB
package ‘bigrquery’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\kenzi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCyckNq\downloaded_packages
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?